# Preparation of quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The collapse of the state vector provides us with a good way of preparing definite states: we begin with a particle in arbitrary state $ |\Psi\rangle$ and measure a variable $\Omega$. If we get a nondegenerate eigenvalue $\omega$ then we have in our hands $|\omega\rangle$. In case when the eigenvalue $\omega$ is degenerate how do we prepare the state we want in its eigen-subspace?

Comment: I'd propose, following your reasoning, to measure another variable which commutes with $\omega$ (and another and another, until the measurement outcomes define the state (that is, you have a complete commuting set of observables)).

Comment: In that case I need to repeat that until complete nondegeneracy is obtained. Is that true?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/551596/how-can-you-tell-that-a-given-operators-eigenspectrum-will-feature-degeneracy

Comment: @Quantumwhisp How would you know? ;)

Comment: @DvijD.C. I don't, it's just guess-work. Simultaneously measureing all the observables to form a complete set of commuting variables would collapse the state to a nondegenerate state, right?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp Yes you are right.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp Yes, that is correct. My point was that you never know in physics what is the complete set of commuting operators. Another way to say the same thing is that you don't know the dimensionality of the Hilbert space of the system you are dealing with. You can always discover new degrees of freedom that you didn't know about and it would uncover some degeneracies that were always present but you didn't know about. Think of a particle on a line, one would think that the position operator forms a complete set of commuting operators. But then someone comes along and discovers spin, etc.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Ah - I see what you're getting at. Yes, you're right, you would never know wether your state is nondegenerate, until you find out there are other observables that aren't yet fixed by your measurement. 
I however got the question in another way: If we KNOW that $\omega$ is degenerate (and that there are other values to be fixed), how do we achieve that?